# How can I subtract one variable from another?

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var totaalBreedte = $("#menuus").width();
    var menuBreedte = $("#eersteMenu").width();
    var over = totaalBreedte - menuBreedte;

    alert(over);  
});
```

For example, when totaalBreedte = 800 and menuBreedte = 400. I can sum the two values, which alerts 1200, but when i substract them like above I recieve 0. I tried to cast them as a number and tried parseInt() but this doesn't make any difference. Someone who knows what i'm missing here?

Comment: They're already integers, `width()` returns an integer or `null` if the selector didn't match any elements. There's no reason `parseInt` should help.

Comment: It works. Something else could be wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/3EAGe/

Comment: working fine here too => http://jsfiddle.net/5gb8f/

Comment: May be both `totaalBreedte` and `menuBreedte` are 600. That seems to be the only possible explanation why you get `1200` on addition and `0` on subtraction. Did you try and alert both values separately?

Comment: ok, was me being stupid... was the end of the day. You're right, they have the same width. Have seen different values before, but that must have been for an other reason. Problem solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code is working perfectly. I have just changed the element selectors for width to a simple int. And it worked correctly. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/KnbEh/

And here is a snapshot;

[image]

You can see the value of the result being sent to alert. What you should do is to check the values for them. As @Vega has already mentioned, it looks like they are both `600` which is why, their sum is 1200, and when you subtract, its a 0. You might want to recheck the values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to look into the actual value of both totaalBreedte and menuBreedte? Tried another browser? You can use for example the Chrome's console to try some JavaScript lines and debug this. Your code seems ok.